# Can I alias one domain to another?

Tags: dns, alias

I am merging two DNS domains.  They are internal so I don't have to worry about fitting into the main DNS system.  They are largely the same: ie they contain mostly the same hosts.

What I want to do is create an alias for one of the domains.

The RFCs say that you can't have an NS record or an MX record the same as a cname (or probably an A record) so I created a zone with only a cname and it works:

zone 1 = example.com (a normal domain)
Try 1:
 zone 2 = sample.internal (a domain with a single alias)
  Unfortunately windows (it would have to be windows wouldn't it) helpfully keeps adding ns records.  grrrr.
Try 2:
zone 2 = internal (a domain)
  contains normal gumpf and one cname

```
sample CNAME example.com.
```

But both gave the same results:

```
nslookup sample.internal
Server:  ns.example.com
Address:  172.16.xx.xx

Name:    example.com
Addresses:  172.16.xx.xx
      172.16.xx.xx
Aliases:  sample.internal
```

but this lookup where fred.example.com exists doesn't work:

```
nslookup fred.sample.internal
Server:  ns.example.com
Address:  172.16.xx.xx

*** ns.example.com can't find fred.sample.internal: Non-existent domain
```

Is it possible to do recursive lookups in an aliased domain?

Comment: I'm going to say this is a bad idea and can result in some problems instead of just rolling out an update for the merged zones.  That said, Windows DNS server stores zones in text zone files and/or the Active Directory.  So, basically are these going to change that often? If not, can you just replicate the settings once by copying the zone data between and not updating the legacy zone ever again?

Comment: I just discovered a new DNS type I'd never known about: the DNAME type.  This all then works like I thought it would.  <br /> The problem is that the two zones hold the same information and I want to have a single authoritative source of data.

Comment: I still question the need/purpose for implementing this for the long-term.  This post discusses some issues [DNAME](http://blacka.com/david/2006/12/04/dns-dname-is-almost-useless/)

Answer (score 10):

Yes you can. There are two primary ways of accomplishing this with DNS (I will use "BIND" configuration examples):

1. Using the DNAME (Delegation NAME) record
2. Overloading a zone file in the BIND configuration

The first option leaves trails of where it originates and how it's set up, while the second one is easiest to implement but requires careful planning and places restrictions on zone usage.

#### DNAME Method

Let's say you want every host within "bad.com" to go to "good.com". First set up the zone in your "named.conf":

```
// Malicious external domain, redirected to "good.com"
zone "bad.com" in {
    type master;
    file "security/good.com";
    check-names ignore;
};
```

The zone file for "good.com" *(remember, this is the zone we're redirecting **to**)* would look something like this:

```
; Name:         security/good.com
; Date:          2/19/2016
; Purpose:      General-use redirection to "good.com" using DNAME 

$TTL 3600
@        IN      SOA     dns.good.com. admin.dns.com. (
                         2016021900 
                         7200 
                         600 
                         2592000 
                         3600 )

         IN      NS      dns1.good.com.
         IN      NS      dns2.good.com.

         IN      DNAME   good.com.
```

When you reload your name server, any DNS queries in the "bad.com" zone will now be delegated to "good.com":

```
> nslookup www.bad.com
Server:         dns1.good.com
Address:        10.9.8.7#53

bad.com         dname = good.com.
www.bad.com     canonical name = www.good.com.
Name:   www.good.com
Address: 10.1.2.3
```

I purposefully used the default behavior of the zone file using a single "@" encompassing the SOA, NS and DNAME records, which makes it easy to just re-use the "security/good.com" zone file for any other such zones you might want to redirect:

```
// Malicious external domain, redirected to "good.com"
zone "bad.com" in {
    type master;
    file "security/good.com";
    check-names ignore;
};

// Another malicious external domain, redirected to "good.com"
zone "worse.com" in {
    type master;
    file "security/good.com";
    check-names ignore;
};

// Yet another malicious external domain, redirected to "good.com"
zone "evil.com" in {
    type master;
    file "security/good.com";
    check-names ignore;
};
```

You get the idea...

Note how the DNAME delegation is displayed in the query results. Some people may not like this, which can be overcome using the second method.

#### Zone File Overload Method

In reality we covered this already above. All we're doing is re-using a zone file with the default records and never ***explicitly referencing the zone name***. In our example, we use the "directory" options but place all the zone files in a folder called "zone", and give the file name the same name as the zone name *(I never liked the "db.xxxx")*:

```
$TTL 14400
@         IN      SOA     dns.good.com. admin.good.com. (
                          2016021900 ; Serial No.
                          1800       ; Refresh
                          600        ; Retry
                          604800     ; Expire
                          3600 )     ; Minimum

          IN      NS      dns1
          IN      NS      dns2
          IN      MX      10 mail
          IN      A       10.11.12.13

; A records

dns1      IN      A       10.9.8.7
dns2      IN      A       10.9.8.6
mail      IN      A       10.9.8.5
files     IN      A       10.9.8.4

; CNAME records

www       IN      CNAME   @
ftp       IN      CNAME   files
```

Now the elements of your "named.conf" file:

```
zone "good.com" in {
    type master;
    file "zones/good.com";
    check-names ignore;
    notify yes;
};
```

Now lets say you want the domain "goodness.com" to essentially be "good.com". Simply re-use the "good.com" file in your "named.conf", but specifying the overloaded zone name:

```
zone "goodness.com" in {
    type master;
    file "zones/good.com";
    check-names ignore;
    notify yes;
};
```

Now when you query for records in "goodness.com", they become the records from the "good.com" zone:

```
> nslookup files.good.com
Server:         dns1.good.com
Address:        10.9.8.7#53

Name:   files.good.com
Address: 10.9.8.4

> nslookup files.goodness.com    
Server:         dns1.good.com
Address:        10.9.8.7#53

Name:   files.goodness.com
Address: 10.9.8.4
```

As above, you must never explicitly reference the zone name in the zone file, but rather use the "@" default reference, and never use fully-qualified domain names as the target of CNAME records that reference A records within the zone.

The drawbacks to this method must be very careful using the "$ORIGIN" directives, and becomes very difficult to use the "$GENERATE" directive. Additionally, it occupies twice the memory in your authoritative server since they are separate zones as far as the server is concerned.

Anyway, this should demonstrate two ways of using DNS to redirect records of one zone to another.

Comment: One issue I'm having with this is that when you query for an A record for bad.com I get "No answer" from Bind and windows 2012r2. windows 2008r2 returns the A record

Comment: A DNAME record in the "good" zone that points to itself doesn't work. Don't do it.

Answer (score 5):

A `CNAME` record aliases a specific domain name to another domain name.

A `DNAME` record aliases all *subdomains* of a specific domain name to the same *subdomain* of another domain name.

Unfortunately the two cannot co-exist together - it's not possible to say:

```
foo   IN CNAME bar    ;; maps the domain
foo   IN DNAME bar    ;; maps the subdomains
```

although there are proposals at the IETF for an alternative that might do both together.

Comment: @Fonzie it actually doesn't, unfortunately.   The DNAME record specifically doesn't cover the name itself, only its subdomains.